# I got unexpected value while i was building module for homework

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, module

I created an HTML file that has two script

it looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='src/moduleOne.js'></script>
    <script src='src/moduleTwo.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the first module of javascript has simple code

```
(function() {
    let hello = 'frank';
})();
```

and the second one has function inside it

```
(function() {
    function problemIsNotOccur() {
        return name === undefined;
    }
    console.log(problemIsNotOccur());
})();
```

**What should happen is the name should return Error name is undefind or return undefined value**
*But*
**name return '' empty string** (I don't why that happen)

Comment: your module 2 will return boolean i.e either true or false, for this it will return false

Comment: @abdulsalamjamaea Your question is not clear. Are looking for a function that accepts a name `parameter` and return an `error` if name is undefined ?

Comment: name variable hasn't declared and it returns an empty string what I expect is Error like a name is undefined or at least name returns undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear in your case name is not defined because is not declared

```
 (function() {
    let name; ///name now is undefined
    function problemIsNotOccur() {
        return name === undefined; /// return true 
    }
    console.log(problemIsNotOccur());
    })();
```

Comment: But if I don't declare name why is it returns empty string why not undefined or certain Error

Comment: because name is use as a property of window object, if you console.log(name)it will return string,

Answer (score 0):

I have just copied your code but instead of using 2 separate files, I put both functions inline and the result is "false" which is what is to be expected. The functions don't make much sense though. The first one only assigns a value to a variable and the other one returns "false" every time because you didn't define "name".

For reference, here is how I tested it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    (function() {
    let hello = 'frank';
})();

    (function() {
    function problemIsNotOccur() {
        return name === undefined;
    }
    console.log(problemIsNotOccur());
})();
    </script
</body>
</html>
```